# swap assignment slower than introducing a new variable?

Tags: python, fft

Okay, I hope the title made somewhat sense. I have made a fast fourier transform code and want to see how it could go faster. So here is the code ('code1') where I do the swapping as the FFT dictates:

```
stp='''
import numpy as nn
D=2**18
N=12
w=(nn.linspace(0,D-1,D)%2**N<(2**N/2))-.5 #square wave
f=w[0:2**N]+nn.zeros(2**N)*1j #it takes only one wavelength from w
'''
code1='''
for m in range(N):
    for l in range(2**m):
        for k in range(2**(N-1-m)):
            t=f[k+l*2**(N-m)]
            f[k+l*2**(N-m)]=(t+f[k+l*2**(N-m)+2**(N-1-m)])
            f[k+l*2**(N-m)+2**(N-1-m)]=(t-f[k+l*2**(N-m)+2**(N-1-m)])*nn.e**(-2*nn.pi*1j*k*2**(m)/2**N)
'''
print(timeit.timeit(setup=stp,stmt=code1,number=1))
```

where I introduce a new variable 't'. This outputs a time of 0.132.

So I thought it should go faster if I did (setup is the same as before):

```
code2='''
for m in range(N):
    for l in range(2**m):
        for k in range(2**(N-1-m)):
            f[k+l*2**(N-m)],f[k+l*2**(N-m)+2**(N-1-m)]=f[k+l*2**(N-m)]+f[k+l*2**(N-m)+2**(N-1-m)],(f[k+l*2**(N-m)]-f[k+l*2**(N-m)+2**(N-1-m)])*nn.e**(-2*nn.pi*1j*k*2**(m)/2**N)
'''
print(timeit.timeit(setup=stp,stmt=code2,number=1))
```

since now I do two assignments instead of three (was my line of thinking). But it appears that this is actually slower (0.152). Anyone has an idea as to why? And does anyone know a way to do this swapping faster than the `t=a,a=f(a,b),b=g(t,b)` I introduced before, since I find it hard to believe that this is the most efficient way.

EDIT: added the actual code instead of the pseudo-code.

MORE EDIT:
I tried running the same without using Numpy. Both are faster, so that's positive, but again the `t=a,a=f(a,b),b=g(t,b)` method appears faster (0.104) than the `a,b=f(a,b),g(a,b)` method (0.114). So the mystery remains.

new code:

```
stpsansnumpy='''
import cmath as mm
D=2**18
N=12
w=[0]*D
for i in range(D):
    w[i]=(i%2**N<(2**N/2))-.5 #square wave
f=w[0:2**N]+[0*1j]*2**N #it takes only one wavelength from w
'''
code1math='''
for m in range(N):
    for l in range(2**m):
        for k in range(2**(N-1-m)):
            t=f[k+l*2**(N-m)]
            f[k+l*2**(N-m)]=(t+f[k+l*2**(N-m)+2**(N-1-m)])
            f[k+l*2**(N-m)+2**(N-1-m)]=(t-f[k+l*2**(N-m)+2**(N-1-m)])*mm.exp(-2*mm.pi*1j*k*2**(m)/2**N)
'''
print(timeit.timeit(setup=stpsansnumpy,stmt=code1math,number=1))
```

and:

```
code2math='''
for m in range(N):
    for l in range(2**m):
        for k in range(2**(N-1-m)):
            f[k+l*2**(N-m)],f[k+l*2**(N-m)+2**(N-1-m)]=f[k+l*2**(N-m)]+f[k+l*2**(N-m)+2**(N-1-m)],(f[k+l*2**(N-m)]-f[k+l*2**(N-m)+2**(N-1-m)])*mm.exp(-2*mm.pi*1j*k*2**(m)/2**N)
'''
print(timeit.timeit(setup=stpsansnumpy,stmt=code2math,number=1))
```

Comment: The behaviour isn't identical.

Comment: Please don't use commas as line endings, they don't mean the same and change what your code means. I assume in your second example, you intended to use commas while in the first, you are separating three statements.

Comment: Grismar it's not supposed to be literal code, but a schematic way of representing it. But I'll just edit it anyway.

Comment: wjandrea you're right. edit: that does not solve the issue btw. Again, this is not my literal code.

Comment: Why does "it appear that this is actually slower"? What test did you do?

Comment: Assuming you actually get identical behavior (fixing up the issues others have mentioned), the performance should be effectively identical. The pack/unpack syntax is *probably* slightly faster, but the difference should pale in comparison to simple function call overhead; making the choice based on speed would be a meaningless microoptimization. If this is not your actual code, we can't help figure out what *other* mistakes you made in the actual code that would produce meaningful speed differences; provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Andrew Jaffe I let my FFT functions (one using the first method, the other using the second, for the rest I just copy-pasted them) on a list of 2**16 elements, and the difference became apparent.

Comment: Wall-clock time is not a good way to check -- too much other stuff going on in your computer. Use (e.g.) `timeit` as in @Grismar's answer.

Comment: ShadowRanger The other mistakes are not relevant since I'm comparing two functions that only differ in the one detail I mentioned. I chose to introduce it like this because the FFT is a rather large and complex thing, and it might discourage some to look at it, while the issue is actually only surrounding this very basic subject. I assumed this small difference in speed might blow up if I try to transform even bigger lists, but I might be wrong about that.

Comment: Andrew Jaffe okay, I'll try that.

Comment: I used timeit (thanks for the tip), and it is slower. Up to over a second (I set number to 1) when I apply both on a list of 2**18 elements. Not a disaster of course, but my main hope coming here was to find an even more efficient way that might take seconds off. But perhaps there isn't, and I guess this topic is a bit too obscure.

Comment: @Antaios: The only way this would make a difference is if `f` was modifying `a` in-place, thereby changing the behavior. Advanced math using `numpy` could easily do this. Again, a [MCVE] is needed to figure out your actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version I see 5 indexing operations, and in the second one I see 6. I’m not surprised that 6 indexing operations (with all the computations you use in them) are more expensive than 5.

Creating a temporary variable, or creating a temporary tuple, is peanuts compared to all the computations you do in these code fragments.

Comment: Ah, so the indexing is the problem, not the assigning so much. I immediately tried out if a method as `t=a, s=b, a=f(t,s), b=g(t,s)` is faster, and it is. So I'm happy.

Comment: @Antaios: Yes, I was thinking about that after I wrote this answer. More intermediate variables are likely good here. Factor out all the common computations. An optimizing compiler would take your code and transform it to avoid all repeated calculations. Python is an interpreter, not a compiler, so there's no optimization going on, you need to do all of that stuff by hand.

Answer (score 3):

It would have been nice if you shared why you think one is slower than the other and if your code would have been formatted properly as Python code should be.

Something like this:

```
from timeit import timeit


def f(a, b):
    return a


def g(a, b):
    return a


def extra_var(a, b):
    t = a
    a = f(a, b)
    b = g(t, b)
    return a, b


def swap_direct(a, b):
    a, b = f(a, b), g(a, b)
    return a, b


print(timeit(lambda: extra_var(1, 2)))
print(timeit(lambda: swap_direct(1, 2)))
```

However, if you had, you would probably have found the same results I did:

```
0.2162299
0.21171479999999998
```

The results are so close that in consecutive runs, either function can appear to be a bit faster or slower.

So, you'd increase the volume:

```
print(timeit(lambda: extra_var(1, 2), number=10000000))
print(timeit(lambda: swap_direct(1, 2), number=10000000))
```

And the mystery goes away:

```
2.1527828999999996
2.1225841
```

The direct swap is actually slightly faster, as expected. What is different about what you were doing that was giving you other results?

You say you're seeing a difference when you implement it in the context of more complicated code - however, this shows it's likely that your code itself is the likely culprit, which is why StackOverflow suggests you share a minimal, reproducible example, so people can actually try what you say happens, instead of having to take your word for it.

In most cases, it turns out someone made a mistake and everything is as expected. In some cases, you get an interesting answer.

Comment: Okay, in that case it apparently depends on f and g or the fact that I'm using Numpy arrays. Didn't think the problem would lie so deep. I'll add my literal code.